# Better way to do prints with tuples?

Tags: python

I am working on a simple mad-libs esque code, but I couldn't find a more efficient way to do this.

```
print madlib1 % (madlib1_answers[0],madlib1_answers[1],madlib1_answers[2],madlib1_answers[3],madlib1_answers[4],madlib1_answers[5],madlib1_answers[6],madlib1_answers[7],madlib1_answers[8],madlib1_answers[9],madlib1_answers[10],madlib1_answers[11],madlib1_answers[12])
```

madlib1 is just a variable string that has %s's for each answer, and the madlibs has 13 answers total.

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet?

Comment: What is the format? Would something like `print ' '.join(map(str, madlib1_answers))`? If you need more complexity, use `str.format` and unpack the tuple into it - `template.format(*madlib1_answers)`.

Comment: Try `madlib1 % tuple(madlib1_answers[:13])`, if `madlib1_answers` is already a tuple then tuple call is not required.

Answer (score 4):

If you switch to using `.format()`, you can just unroll `madlib1_answers` like this:

```
print madlib1.format(*madlib1_answers)
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to use the [format specification language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

One warning, if you have more values than you do specifiers in your unformatted string, it will throw away any extra values.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can accomplish this:

```
# If madlib1_answers is already a tuple with correct number of elements
print madlib1 % madlib1_answers

# If you need to crop the tuple:
print madlib1 % madlib1_answers[:13]

# If it's not a tuple yet
print madlib1 % tuple(madlib1_answers)
```

Comment: What if `madlib1_answers` is not a tuple or it contains more items than the placeholders provided in  `madlib1`?

Comment: `print madlib1 % tuple(madlib1_answers[:13])` would satisfy the OP.